# how to use pointers in a matrix. what does this line of code do/mean: int r=**(++b);

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix

I dont understand why my answer is 4? can anyone please explain matrix and pointers. I mean I know what matrix are, they are a 2 row table but I dont know how to use pointers in a matrix, like in the example here :

```
int m[][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int (*b)[3]=&m[0];
int r=**(++b);
std::cout << r;
```

Comment: Did you mean to put `**` in the question too?

Comment: yes i did! @doctorlove

Comment: @user2843560 I corrected it for you by editing the title earlier. Hope that's ok.

Comment: did i put one * in my title? sorry thank you @Streppel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer can be more easily understood if we consider `m[][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};` to be `m[][3]={ {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9} };`.

`(*b)[3] = &m[0]` is a pointer to an array of length `3` that points to the *first row* of elements in `m[][3]`, that is, `{1, 2, 3}`.

When you increment it (by doing `++b`), it will then point to the second row of elements in `m[][3]`, which will be `{4, 5, 6}`.

Then, `r` is assigned to the value that `b` points to, which, because it is dereferenced twice, will be the first integer value in the row pointed by `b`.

```
               +------+------+------+   +------+------+-------+
               |   1  |   2  |  3   |   |  4   |  5   |   6   |
               +------+------+------+   +------+------+-------+
                       Gets the value '4'  ^  and not the row's address,
                                           |  which *b points to
    int r = **b----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion, such play with pointers is not recommended in practical use, but just for academic understanding:

```
int m[][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int (*b)[3]=&m[0]; // b is a pointer to an array of 3 
                    // and is initialized to point to 1st row of m.
```

.

```
int r=**(++b);
```

Here we first increment `b`. This means `b` now points to second row of `m`.
Then we dereference it twice, to give the 1st element in second row of `m` (4)

Comment: Would clearly not use this code semantic in any practical work... Still the answer is very good!